# Implementing reference counts with C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, reference-counting

I'm working on my digital signal processing framework. To provide a data exchange interface, I wrap all buffers in a Data class, which has a reference count based GC mechanism(the system is simple enough so I believe ref count can handle this).

It works like this:

1. When a Data instance is constructed, it sets its ref count to zero.
2. When the instance is dispatched to N DSP modules, add N to its ref count.
3. When a DSP module finishes with the instance, it reduces the ref count.
4. When the ref count decreases to zero, it **delete this;**

However I found out that there is memory leak in my program.

To debug, I added static variables m_alloccount and m_freecount to the Data class to record the time of allocation and freeing. Then I pause the execution at random times, only finding out there is just slight difference between the two numbers.

E.g. in different trials:

```
Trial         1   2    3      4
m_alloccount  12  924  34413  364427
m_freecount   11  923  34412  364425
```

But the fact is that the memory usage is still growing. I believe all memory allocation is bound to the Data class. Really can't figure out the reason now.

```
int Data::m_alloctime=0;
int Data::m_freetime=0;

Data::Data(DataPinOut*parent, int type, int size)
:m_ptr(NULL)
,m_parent(parent)
,m_refcnt(0)
,m_type(type)
,m_size(size)
{
    if(size>0)
        m_ptr=new char[TypeSizeLookup()*size];
    m_alloctime++;
}

Data::~Data()
{
    delete [] (char*)m_ptr;
    m_freetime++;
}

void Data::Delete()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex>*lock=new std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m_mutex);

    if(m_refcnt>1)
    {
        m_refcnt--;
        delete lock;
    }
    else
    {
        delete lock;
        delete this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used `valgrind`?

Comment: Is this multi-threaded?

Comment: Hand off  a `std::shared_ptr` and don't worry about the counts yourself.

Comment: Have you looked at `std::shared_ptr`, the standard reference counting facility in C++11?

Comment: Windows so no valgrind:( Since I'm using C++11 features so it might be simple to compile under Linux, but it's still my last choice... I  gotta try out the shared_ptr. Thanks for your replies :)

Comment: How are you counting the sizes of things allocated and freed?  The byte sizes you've listed seem a bit suspicious, such as including byte-oriented objects such as C-style strings or network message buffers.  Are you sure you don't just have an off-by-one error in your accounting logic?

Comment: @JoeZ they are counts

Comment: Oh, ok, they're counts.  So at the point where they pause, there's one or two objects live.  That doesn't sound like a memory leak at all.  If the process size continues to increase, that may just reflect fragmentation in the heap.

Comment: @JoeZ agreed, I would like more information as to how this was determined to have a memory leak

Comment: @JoeZ What I do is simply m_alloccount++ in the ctor and m_freecount++ in the dtor... And I use the new and delete[] functions.

Comment: @babel92 could you please tell us how you determined there is a memory leak? thanks

Comment: @imsoconfused Eh, I assume in a page based memory managing OS like Windows, if the memory usage increases by at least 1 page(4KB), it's memory leak. Is this right？

Comment: Not necessarily. It may, but it also may not. I must not have all the information you do. Are you using Visual Studio? If so please use this http://vld.codeplex.com/

Comment: @imsoconfused Unfortunately I'm using gcc with Codeblocks:( In fact, the usage grows at a speed of nearly 1page/sec... I think I need to use shared_ptr and if it won't work I have to switch to Visual Studio..

Comment: @babel92:  That should be fine in a single-threaded task.  In a multithreaded task, `foo++` and `foo--` aren't guaranteed to be thread-safe.  But if you're single-threaded you're fine.  If your task's virtual memory size as reported by the OS is growing slowly with time, that may just be due to fragmentation on the heap and not actual memory leakage.

Comment: @imsoconfused The bad thing is every DSP block in my program has its own thread:( I've protected the ++ and -- operation on ref count with std::lock_guard and it should be atomic now. I don't think it's slow because it grows from 8KB to 30KB in half a minute...

Comment: @babel92 unfortunately we don't know your program's expected memory profile at all, and unless we get some hard data on a memory leak, then I don't see how anyone can help you further apart from the usual leak-mitigation techniques

Comment: @imsoconfused It's a simple data transfer model - one block allocs data and the next destroys it... I use ref count because one output may connect to more than one inputs. So I expect the memory usage should be at a "steady state". And since the source code is not pretty short, I believe you may not have the patience to read through it so I'm only expecting some advises. Thanks:)

Comment: hm, in that case, agreed it smells like a leak. I'd still suggest VS + leak detector to cut out all this effort of hunting. otherwise, we have a paradox here - your destructors don't throw, and your alloc/free counts match during runs

Comment: so unless your destructor itself fails to actually free the data, it must be with another object

Comment: @imsoconfused Eh.. What does "throw" mean here? Exception?

Comment: yeah - basically that the destructor actually executed entirely

Comment: @imsoconfused I've updated a piece of my Data code. Would you mind taking a look on it?

Comment: couple questions - 1) why cast in the destructor? it looks unnecessary or indicative of another issue. 2) keep your lock on the stack for better performance - std::lock_guard<mutex> lock(m_mutex); 3) if this simple class really is the issue, it has to be some race condition with the ref counts or something

Comment: maybe your ref counts are unsigned, so they rollover? just guessing now, it's hard to tell

Comment: @imsoconfused 1) Because I defined the m_ptr as void* and allocated it with a unit of char. 2) I tried, but it gets an access violation when destructing the lock_guard, bacause it access the m_mutex, which is already destroyed by **delete this;** As for the refcount, they are int... And this can only happen when I connect a block to 2^31 inputs :)

Comment: @imsoconfused I gotta sleep...  If shared_ptr won't work I will try out Visual Studio. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please move extended discussion to [chat], thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, a memory leak of just one or two regardless of the amount of internal operations indicates a leak of an input or output variable. Check the accounting consistency of the external interface of your system.

`std::shared_ptr` is nice because being standard, it is automatically suitable as an external interface. The user can interact with ref-counted objects without knowing the management details defined by `DSP`.

Other than that, there's not much we can do to intuit what's happening in your program.

Comment: If he's pausing at random times, those numbers don't really mean much - the differences are probably just the live objects at that time. I'm more suspicious as to how he has determined it's a memory leak when it could be fragmentation not leading to memory handback etc

Comment: @imsoconfused I'm supposing the table of trials he posted were complete operations from input to final output. But it's quite possible he simply printed the statistics before disposing of the final output object. That might or might not be considered a bug.

Comment: nope - he states in the question "Then I pause the execution at random times, only finding out there is just slight difference between the two numbers."

Comment: @imsoconfused Yeah, but that might be different from the trials. I could be wrong.

Comment: oh word, yeah that's another interpretation. I just use Intel VTune/Inspector and cut right to the point

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I need to try the shared_ptr and clean up my interface.

Answer (score 0):

How are you maintaining your counters?  If your counter decrement/test is not atomic you might be leaking *decrements* which would prevent the object from ever reaching a refcount of 0.

Comment: I use std::lock_guard and a mutex to protect every function related to ref count operations.

Answer (score 0):

*Step 2. Add n refs when dispatched.*

Are modules guaranteed to be dispatched? Based on your simple algorithm statement a created module that is not dispatched has no mechanism by which its ref count would decrement and be deleted.

Comment: Yes. Every block's thread wait for all its input pins to be loaded and then do its work. Afterwards it decreases ref counts of input data.

Comment: And there are no fault paths that would result in an undispatched data instance?

Comment: Not likely because in my testing example there are only three blocks... A->B->C ....

Comment: Back in the olden days of COM, before shared ptr and the like, the most common cause of ref count leaks was improper derefs in error conditions so maybe something to consider since it sounds like you are managing that explicitly. Best of luck.